# Image to video conversion with ffmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a video showing one image per second using ffmpeg with node-fluent-ffmpeg. I'm using this code as shown on the examples, but I can only get a 1 second video. How can I modify the parameters to get 1 images per seconds and get a video with length that allow to show all images?

```
    var proc = ffmpeg('/images/%09d.jpg'))
    .fps(1)
    .on('end', function() {
         console.log('file has been converted succesfully');
    })
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
    })
    .save(path.resolve('/output/video.m4v'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the parameter I was looking for is inputFPS so I add `.inputFPS(1)` to the code